# @QueryParam regex expression

Tags: java, regex, rest, jersey

I am using Jersey for Rest and have a method that accepts `@QueryParam.`

However, the users may send `@QueryParam.` like this:

`contractName#` where `#` is a number from 0-155.

How can I define it in QueryParam (like regex expression)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify the regexp. However, you can define a custom Java type to represent that query param and implement your own conversion from String to that type - see http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e255 (example 2.15).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do it with QueryParam, but you can get the list of parameters directly:

```
@GET
public String get(@Context UriInfo ui) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = ui.getQueryParameters();
}
```

and iterate through that looking for keys that match your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET
public String get (@QueryParam(value="param") String param){

 boolean test =testYourParamWithNativeRegexpTools(param);
 if( test==false)return 400;
 else //work
.....
}
```