# Getting query parameters with similar prefixes in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@QueryParam regex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672385/queryparam-regex-expression)

I can process an incoming request where there are multiple copies of the same query parameter:

```
// http://localhost:8080/myService?data=1&data=2 
@GET 
public String get(@QueryParam("data") List<String> data)
```

I would like the ability to group data with similar prefixes.  For example

```
// http://localhost:8080/myService?dataOne=1&dataTwo=2 
@GET 
public String get(@QueryParam("data*") List<String> data)
```

Is there a way to do something like this in Jersey?  Right now the only way I can see is by programmatically parsing the query params using UriInfo.

Comment: You have to define a custom type. Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672385/queryparam-regex-expression)

Comment: It's not clear to me how a custom type could be associated with queryparams that have the same prefix, but are not identical.  In the example noted in the link, 2.1.5, you still need to specify the exact parameter name: "@QueryParam("some-color") CustomQueryType color".